# Handling the keyboard when TextInput is inserted in absolute view in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-softkeyboard, absolute

Basically I have a login screen with an absolute view which contains TextInput components for Username and Password.When keyboard pops up It covers Input fields. So far I have gone through other questions and tutorials but I could not find how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the keyboard will cover all of the input fields at-least one of them at the top will be visible.

Try this,set the focus on the next text input on onSubmitEditing of the last one.

```
<TextInput 
  style = {styles.titleInput}
  returnKeyType = {"next"}
  autoFocus = {true}
  placeholder = "Title"
  onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
    this.refs.SecondInput.focus(); 
  }}
/>
<TextInput
  ref='SecondInput'
  style = {styles.descriptionInput}          
  multiline = {true}
  maxLength = {200}
  placeholder = "Description" />
```